# Cross-Origin Request blocked only when file uploads/downloads are involved

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have an Angular application that makes a request to a Spring Boot RESTful API. I have, for development purposes, set a very loose CORS policy in my Spring Boot (please note, to any reading this and potentially copying or pasting, these are not meant to be secure production values).

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, xsrf-token, authorization");

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Location");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "xsrf-token");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }
```

A `@Configuration` class that consumes it:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private SimpleCORSFilter corsFilter;

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.addFilterBefore(corsFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class).authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**")
                .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN").antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/public").permitAll().and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().httpBasic()
                .realmName("test").and().csrf().disable();

    }
}
```

Typically, the communication between the apps works just find. I can retrieve and post JSON data without issue. However, whenever I attempt to either upload an image or run some code that is supposed to download a file, I receive the following error in my browser (Firefox) console:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at http://localhost:8092/report/csv/detail.
> (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

The controller endpoint (Java):

```
@RequestMapping("/csv/detail")
public ResponseEntity<?> getDetailedCSV(@RequestBody ReportRequestDTO dto) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    byte[] contents;
    try {
        contents = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(reportService.getPDFSummary((dto))));
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
        headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(contents, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        return response;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

    }
}
```

The getPDFSummary method:

```
@Override
public String getPDFSummary(ReportRequestDTO req) {
    String outputName = outDir + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".pdf";
    List<SummaryReport> rows = new ArrayList<>();

    if (req.getStatusType() == ReportStatus.ALL) {
        rows = summaryRepo.getSummaryReportAllStatus(req.getPropertyIDs(), req.getItemIDs(), req.getStart(),
                req.getEnd());
    } else {
        boolean isOpen = req.getStatusType() == ReportStatus.OPEN;
        rows = summaryRepo.getSummaryReport(isOpen, req.getPropertyIDs(), req.getItemIDs(), req.getStart(),
                req.getEnd());
    }

    String html = convertRepsToHtml(rows);
    PdfConverterExtension.exportToPdf(outputName, html, "", options);
    return outputName;
}
```

This Angular service that contacts the Spring Boot application:

```
@Injectable()
export class ReportService {
  private baseEndpoint: String = 'http://localhost:8092';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getReport(req: ReportRequestModel): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.http.post(
      `${this.baseEndpoint}/report/${req.exportType}`,
      req,
      { responseType: 'blob' }
    );
  }
}
```

While I have encountered similar issues before, I had assumed the CORSFilter in my Java code would have prevented the error. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try another browser, like Chrome?

Comment: In Chrome, I actually receive different errors: `[Violation] 'load' handler took 891ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 62ms`

Comment: Chrome's error message helped me out. The issue is now resolved. The problem was that the Java app was writing to the assert directory of the Angular app, forcing it to recompile and reload (I was using `ng serve` with the Angular CLI). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but I suppose this answer help you somehow

I faced same problem once and after studding some of the points, I realize that spring boot provide some extended level of security for CORS origins, to restrict CROSS SITE ATTACK.

We discuss it later, first we comes to the point,

The code which you written in class SimpleCORSFilter is mainly responsible for header level security when your work with any of the CORS origin.

For verify this check your response header using inspect element(Point - 1).

Check each of the header element which you required or used for executing your front-end code (Anguler code as per you mention earlier). Some param like content-type, content-disposition are required for downloading file. I suppose you’re not mention it properly or not use as per spring boot standards(Point - 2).

If this parameter is missing then send it in your response, I’m not sure your code is working or not but it’s a better practice when your work with spring boot send your multipart file as Resource with each of header param like

content-type : file MIME type, 
Content – Disposition : file name and action you perform : attachment / inline (Point - 3).

In some of the cases this all parameter are there still you not able to download (which I face),

The solution is you add that parameter as response but not allow them to access by CORS origin.

For that you need to set some required parameter in “Access-Control-Expose-Headers”(Point - 4).
also add some other params which you want to add.

> 1. Right Click browser -> select inspect element -> Go in network pane  ->  Click on requested url -> In newly open block you see the request and their relevant content -> Go in response header option
> 2. Add debugger on front-end code -> console.log(“”)
> 3. Go the end point -> Take Resource param -> Add file as OutputStream   -> Send it as ResponseEntity

```
Path path = Paths.get(<directory-path>).normalize();
Path filePath = path.resolve(fileName).normalize();
Resource resource = new UrlResource(filePath.toUri());
Return ResponseEntity.ok
        .contentType(MediaType.<MIME-Type>)
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, “attachment; filename=””+ resource.filename())
        .body(resource);
```

> 4. SimpleCORSFilter class -> doFilter() method -> add

```
response.setHeader(“Access-Control-Expose-Headers”, “xsrf-token, X-Total-Results, Authorization, Content-type, Content-Disposition”)
```

Still you face some problem mention in comment I'll send one demo for this.